Altium PCB error - Comma expected at line
I am getting this popup

every time I open the PCB file of my Altium project.
There is a similar question here Link: Altium Comma expected , and I tried the things suggested in the comments of it.
Tried creating a new project, added Schematics to it, but still after importing the changes into PCB, the error still exists. Also tried creating a new PCB file and importing everything to it, but no luck.
Even when I close the Project, and just open the PCB file, it still shows error.
This error window pops up again and again when working with the PCB layout. Does anybody know how this error actually occurs and how to solve this error? (I tried using Altium latest 24.9.1, and older versions 18.1.9, 19.1.5 too.) Can this be something related with the components used in it?

I see a weird (?) claim online that a printer needs to be installed... such as XPS document writer, PDF etc..

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I already have XPS document writer, Microsoft print to PDF and an HP printer already installed. Maybe there must be something else related to it.. Could you share the link to that page you found?

@Akshay James. I suggest you log-in to your online Altium account, and pose the question directly in the Altium forum or to the Altium technical support team.

Try subdividing the problem: starting with a blank PCB, import half the components, then the other half, and so on. Does it reduce to one component? A set of components? Check their footprints, anything suspicious? Indirect strings perhaps?

This isn't an electrical engineering question. This is a support question for Altium about their software you are entitled for getting support as a paying customer.

@AkshayJames Here is the link.

@TimWilliams, I did the above, but I didn't find anything suspicious. Thanks for your suggestions.

Thanks everyone for your help and comments for immediate tips. I've created a ticket in Altium support. I will ask them for the exact cause of it.
